# Creating KeyVault in Azure with no user

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager

Is there a way in Azure to create keyvault without any user? I am trying to follow the documentation but dont see any command that will achieve this in one line?

```
New-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName my-test -ResourceGroupName abc -Location "Brazil South"
```

Any powershell command I can add above to not create any access policy or principal user?

Comment: After your code, you code `Remove-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy` to delete the previously created policy

Comment: if my reply is helpful, please mark it as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template to create a vault with no access policy - see: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-key-vault-create/azuredeploy.json and just remove this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-key-vault-create/azuredeploy.json#L105-L114

You can deploy that with PowerShell using New-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment.

Answer (score 0):

The `New-AzureRmKeyVault` create keyvault with access policy by default, if you want to achieve this in one line, you could use powershell pipeline, try the command below, it works fine on my side.

```
New-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName '<VaultName>' -ResourceGroupName '<ResourceGroupName>' -Location 'East US' | Remove-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -ObjectId "<ObjectId of your signin user or service principal>"
```

**Update**:

I suppose you create the keyvault via a user account, you could get the `ObjectId` via [`Get-AzureRmADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermaduser?view=azurermps-6.9.0),`-UserPrincipalName` is your account.

Complete command:

```
$ObjectId = (Get-AzureRmADUser -UserPrincipalName "xxxx@xxxx.com").Id
New-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName '<VaultName>' -ResourceGroupName '<ResourceGroupName>' -Location 'East US' | Remove-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -ObjectId $ObjectId
```

Comment: How will you get - ObjectId of your signin user or service principal? I dont see any powershell command for this?